# ビッグバンドの音源データセットが欲しいです

Tags: 深層学習

機械学習を行っている者です。
データセットにビッグバンドのパラ音源が欲しいのですが、普通のwav音源のようなデータセットが見つかりません…。
「Big Band music dataset」などで探しているのですが他に見つけるいい方法があるのでしょうか…？

Comment: 参考までに、[Royalty Free Music tracks by genre Big Band](https://www.proudmusiclibrary.com/en/genre/big-band) というサイトがありますが、配布されているのはパラデータではない様です。

Comment: なるほど…ありがとうございます！